# Uncheck box in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button to clear several unlocked cells on a form that uses the following code:

```
Range("F5").ClearContents
Range("C16").ClearContents
Range("F23", "F27").ClearContents
Range("F34").ClearContents
Range("E37").ClearContents
Range("F38", "J39").ClearContents
Range("F41", "J42").ClearContents
Range("F44", "J44").ClearContents
Range("F56", "G56").ClearContents
Range("F65", "G66").ClearContents
OptionButtons("No").Value = xlOn
OptionButtons("None") = xlOn
```

The above works fine for clearing the ranges and setting the option buttons. I have a checkbox I would also like to include in this code and 'uncheck' but I'm not sure how to do this. Please can someone let me know how to set a checkbox to unchecked with VBA?

Also, is there a better way to clear the data in the cells?

Thank you

Comment: You can uncheck a single checkbox with `activesheet.checkboxes("Check Box 1").value = xlOff`.  Change the name of the checkbox accordingly.

Comment: `Range("F5, C16, F23, F34, E37, F38, J39, F41, J42, F44, J44, F56, G56, F65, G66").ClearContents`

Comment: What type of check box are you talking about?  A sheet check box? If yes, is it of Form or ActiveX type?

Answer (score 1):

I was just building a macro with such a button, maybe you can use it:

```
Sub Unchecker()
    Dim chkBox As Excel.CheckBox
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each chkBox In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        chkBox.Value = xlOff
    Next chkBox
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```